# Use sandbox account as regular account(Apple). How to deal with itunes account creation not allowed app store error?

Tags: ios, sandbox, appstore-sandbox, apple-id

I created Apple Id account and initially used for testing purchases as a sandbox account. For now, I want this account to use as a regular account. So, I deleted it from the sandbox users list, logged into the device, but I cannot install any of apps. The annoying dialog appears: **iTunes account creation not allowed**

[image]

How can I deal with that dialog?

How can I transform the sandbox account for regular using?

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Ok, I went to Apple support, wasting many hours, but they didn't know what and why did it happen. So, Apple didn't help me. I used another account. 
I will wait more time and write here the result

Comment: I am also facing this issue, any solution yet?

Comment: @RizwanAhmedShivalli no(
I even had the call with Apple support, but no success, I created new Apple ID and use it.

Comment: Ya the Apple Support also said they cannot change the sandbox account to a normal account so I have also decided to create a new Apple id